# Google drive script to list all available template

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to search in the Google Drive API and Script guides to see is there any method which is available to list all available template google documents. Any points would be much appreciated

Comment: I have found one way to get the folder Id of the templates folder and list all the file ids. But was looking for is there any google api method to directly get all the template documents

Comment: AFAIK you can [list all Drive files](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) but I haven't seen any method specifically for templates. Try asking for a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).